# Python: DictWriter overwrites rows when file reaches certain size

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I've encountered a strange problem when using DictWriter to add rows to the end of a csv inside a loop.
When the file reaches 12288 bytes, rows are no longer added and are replaced instead.
To check this, I ran a simple test:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
test=pd.DataFrame(columns=('key1','key2','key3','key4','key5'))
test.to_csv("testwrite.csv",index=False)

for i in range(500): 
    headers={}
    data={}
    words={'key1':'col1','key2':'col2','key3':'col3','key4':'col4','key5':'col5'}

    for k,v in words.items():
        headers[k]='keyval'+str(i)
        data[k]='colval'+str(i)

    with open("testwrite.csv", 'r+',newline='\n') as f:
        header=next(csv.reader(f))
        dw=csv.DictWriter(f, header)
        dw.writerow(data)
        f.close()
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have a solution to this?

Comment: Why are you calling `f.close()` in the `with` context?

Comment: I am not familiar with Python and wanted to make sure that the file was being closed properly. I've taken it out now, but it doesn't affect the result.